# Cos(∞) in limits.

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I have to solve question $\lim_{x \to 0} x^2 cos (\frac{2}{x})$ . It is in the form of $f(x)\circ g(x)$ so it is $\lim_{x \to 0} x^2 \times \lim_{x \to 0} cos (\frac{2}{x})$ .

I am getting $0 \times cos (\infty)$, but I don't know how to proceed.  What should I do to complete the question?

Comment: $\cos(\infty)$ is indeterminate, but always between $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: @Arthur I know cos(∞) don't exist. But what to do in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $|x^2 \cos(2/x)| \le x^2$  for all $x \ne 0$. Hence

$$x^2 \cos(2/x) \to 0$$

for $x \to 0$.

Comment: How you got inequality? An what to do hen I got cos(∞)? Just suppose than anything multiplied by 0 is zero (most of the time) ?

Comment: $|\cos(t)| \le 1$ for all $t$.

Comment: And what about cos(∞) ?

Comment: The idea was that if $|\cos(t)|$ is always less than or equal to 1, for all t, then it doesn't matter about $\cos(\infty)$.  Ultimately, your limit goes to zero because the $x^2$ term goes to zero.  When zero is multiplied by a number whose absolute value is always less than or equal to 1, you get 0 no matter what the number is

Comment: Please check my answer also @MichaelStachowsky

Answer (score 0):

It came in my exam today and I lost my marks :/ but now I got correct solution :)

$-1\leq \cos \theta \leq 1$

Let $\theta = \lim\limits_{x\to 0} \dfrac 2x$

$-1\leq \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\cos \dfrac 2x \leq 1$

Multiplying with $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} x^2$

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} -x^2\leq \lim\limits_{x\to 0} x^2 .\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\cos \dfrac 2x \leq \lim\limits_{x\to 0} x^2$

$0\leq \lim\limits_{x\to 0} x^2 \cos \dfrac 2x  \leq 0$

Therefore $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} x^2 \cos \dfrac 2x=0$

I seriously wished if someone answered in this way yesterday,I would have not lost my mark in todays exam.

Comment: You're right.  In fact, people *did* answer this way, but their answers were simpler.  As a good exercise, try to prove that the two answers are equivalent